# Authorization (401) issue with Nginx

Tags: nginx

I have a Nginx virtualhost with the following content:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location /.well-known {
        alias /usr/local/etc/letsencrypt-webroot/.well-known;
    }
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.domain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.domain.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dh.pem;

        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_cookie_path / "/; secure; HttpOnly";
        auth_basic "No no no!";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }
}
```

I'm having a problem when the URL is `/.well-known/...`. I get a 401 because it keeps asking for credentials.

So my questions are:

- Why is `/.well-known` user-protected? Shouldn't it be processed before reaching the `location /` in the SSL section, which is the one requiring authentication?
- How can I fix this? Basically I need that everything requested to the proxy needs authentication except for `/.well-known`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try opening http://yourserver/.well-known/ instead of https://yourserver/.well-known.

If this works reconsider moving both location blocks to single `server {...}` block.

//edit to make it working you have to either remove redirect from. well-known block or adding it to block in https server definition.

Comment: I was using http. Moving the `.well-known` block to the other section works.

Answer (score 3):

```
  location /.well-known {
    auth_basic off;
  }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation for your code rather than posting code only. Additional explanation will be more helpful .